# How can I plot some values of plotted vector in Matlab with different marker?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have a vector x with 1000 values, plots in matlab using semiology function, I want to change the marker of the values x(1:10:1000) to be different. How can I do that?

I tried to use the following way with using the new marker as circle:

```
semiology(x(1:10:1000), y(1:10:1000), 'o');
```

but that plots the first 100 values, I mean the new marker will be shown on the first 100 values of older plot, it will not be distributed on the whole old plot. However, I need the new marker to be shown on the same values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess from your question that the orginal plot with all the points is cleared. If so then the command `hold on` can be used to preserve that plot. for your case:

```
semilogy(x, y, 'o'); % Plot the entire vector with the 'o' marker
hold on; % Do not let semilogy replace the current plot 
semilogy(x(1:10:1000), y(1:10:1000), 'x'); % mark every 10th point with an 'x'
```